# text displaying out of UiTableViewCell section

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

My `UITableview` is displaying the data, but the text in one section is moving out of the box and displaying in other section..i don't know why?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=3;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.40 green:0.40 blue:0.40 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"School Hours:"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take in time: %@ \nDissmiss time:%@ \nPhone No: %@ ",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1){cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=3;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.40 green:0.40 blue:0.40 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Principal"];
        NSString *thumbs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        UIImage *thumbs1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                  [NSURL URLWithString:thumbs]]];
       // cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:th];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  ",[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];}
```

Can any one let me know what went wrong. i even set header and footer for the sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the height of cell For example...

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *titleString = yourTitleString;///here just write your string here
    NSString *detailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take in time: %@ \nDissmiss time:%@ \nPhone No: %@ ",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    CGSize titleSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize detailSize = [detailString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return detailSize.height+titleSize.height;
}
```

And i just set the code for the common cell for Dynamic height of cell see bellow code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"YourTitle";
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([@"YourTitle" sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take in time: %@ \nDissmiss time:%@ \nPhone No: %@ ",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take in time: %@ \nDissmiss time:%@ \nPhone No: %@ ",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: HI Paras is i am not sure about the height i mean it may vary time to time

Comment: may be here this problem occur bcoz our data is more than the visibility of our cell so this type of problem occure..

Comment: @pradeepj you set the height of the cell from starting dude??

Comment: if my height of the cell changes dynamically toward the data input

Comment: yes possible but just implement your logic also.. i do this type of logic its call dynamic height of every UITableViewCell..

Comment: best option for that is to Create custem UILabel set text,frame to it and add it in cell.....

Comment: no no dude you can also add the dyanamic height of uilable with its data size dude.. i find one method for that but here you set the height of cell then check it its cover it..

Comment: @nizamabunti if i have a long label how this will display in cell?

Comment: @pradeepj just set the height of that cell related frame of uilable dude.. :) simple dude

Comment: you have to set UILabel width  as UITAbleView cell width and give noofline to label ..and according to hight of label you have to set hight of cell.

Comment: @pradeepj now try this dude.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi Awesome bro u rocks, u gave the simple way to solve my prob.!!! thank a ton.

Answer (score 0):

For such a huge data you need to truncate the data to display it.
For this you can use:

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
 cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Another option is you need to adjust your tableViewCell's height using the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate.